# Use calendar versioning for Python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi

I prefer the calendar versioning scheme (see [calver.org](https://calver.org)) over the semantic approach. But when I use calendar versioning in a Python package, PyPI removes the zero padding in the month. For example, in `setup.py`, if the version number is declared as `version='19.03'` then PyPI hosts the package as 19.3 (no zero padding).

Is there a way to force PyPI to acknowledge the zero-padded month or is the `YYYY.0M` scheme not supported for Python packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The issue isn't PyPI, it's the way `setuptools` normalizes the version number when building a distribution.

Take this simple `setup.py` which defines a minimal package:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='calver-test',
    version='2019.03.29',
    packages=[],
)
```

If you run `python setup.py sdist`, this will produce a file `calver-test-2019.3.29.tar.gz` that has the following structure:

```
calver-test-2019.3.29
├── PKG-INFO
├── calver_test.egg-info
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── setup.cfg
└── setup.py
```

If you manually unpack the `tar.gz` file, modify the occurrences of `2019.3.29` to `2019.03.29` in the `PKG-INFO` files, and re-pack it into a file named `calver-test-2019.03.29.tar.gz`, and upload it to PyPI, it will retain the zero padding.

Example here: https://pypi.org/project/calver-test/2019.03.29/

Obviously this process isn't ideal if this is your intended behavior, so perhaps it would make sense to open an issue on the [setuptools issue tracker](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues).

Comment: That's a lot of work just to get a 0. I'll just use the `YY.MM` style. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, to validate if the parsed version string is working as expected:

```
from pkg_resources import parse_version
assert parse_version("19.03" ) == parse_version("19.3")
assert (
      parse_version("19.01")
    < parse_version("19.02")
    < parse_version("19.03")
    < parse_version("19.04")
    < parse_version("19.05")
    < parse_version("19.06")
    < parse_version("19.07")
    < parse_version("19.08")
    < parse_version("19.09")
    < parse_version("19.10")
    < parse_version("19.11")
    < parse_version("19.12")
)
```

Ref: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/distribution.html